# How to create Table from JSON Data with angularJS and PHP backend

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am working with PHP backend and AngularJS, in login.php file, I have a query, and I save the result of this query in variable $result, and in app.JS, I put this result in a cookie and I diplay it in view.html file. The problem is that I get the result of query in Json form, but me, I want to have it as table so I can with ng-repeat to display this result in html file.

**login.php**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM client WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'") ';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  {
while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
    $someArray[] = $res;

    }   

for($i = 0; $i < count($someArray); ++$i)
  {    
       $result["cc"] = $someArray ;  
       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window,$rootScope,$cookieStore,$cookies){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'mdp' : $scope.mdp
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);
                $state.go('view');  
            $cookieStore.put('cookie',data.cc);     
        }
       $scope.name=$cookieStore.get('cookie');     
});
```

**view.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="loginCtrl">

    {{Name}}
</div>
```

So as a result, in view.html, I get the result of query but in Json form, I tried to make scope.query=data; and make an ng-repeat in view.html, but I don't get any result. How can I do please?

Comment: There should be some repeating key in the json data which you need to use for ng-repeat

Comment: How can I do please, I didn't get your suggestion!

Comment: Please use `console.dir($scope.name)` @ last and post the image.

Comment: I still have the same result( the result of query in Json form), I don't get anything new with console.dir!!

Comment: Post the complete code for your view please.

Comment: done! in fact in html view, I want just to display the result of query but with ng-repeat with a table , but now I am getting all the result in a big paragraph in Json form!!

Comment: @Salma, please post the screen shot of console result by expanding the result.

Comment: @JijoCleetus , done! I posted the screen of result that I get!

Comment: By seeing the screenshot, you can use
`<ul>
<li ng-repeat="n in name">{{n.CodeEnvoiColis}}</li>
</ul>`

Comment: Thank you , your can write it as a response so I can mark it as right response! but thetre is just a problem, is that I get all codes in the same line and no space between them!!

Comment: Ok, now I manage this problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, Now we got the result by using ul,li elements. You can try the same using `<table>`. you need to repeat the `<tr>` elements like `ng-repeat="n in name"` and inside `<td>{{{n.CodeEnvoiColis}}</td><td>{{n.CrbtColis}}</td>`

Comment: Yes that's what I did! it s working , thank you so much!!

Comment: Try some table formating and use the same for styling

Comment: Thank yo so much!

Comment: Can you put it as response so I can mark it as right please!

Comment: I have already did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of result in json format

```
result = [{
 name: A,
 value: 1
},
{
 name: B,
 value: 2
},
{
 name: C,
 value: 3
}]
```

then HTML Table would be

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Value</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat= "item in result">
           <td>{{item.name}}</td>
           <td>{{item.value}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```